# Laravel 5 Testing - Setting up database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I understand that Laravel 5 is unfinished, but so far I got around that pretty well.

My question concerns testing. Previously you were able to `Artisan::call('migrate')` in your test to set up the database.

How should we do this in Laravel 5?

I tried `Artisan::call('migrate')`, `$this->app['artisan']->call('migrate')`, including the class via `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan`, nothing of which worked.

Comment: Someone in the IRC channel would know. That is the best place to ask since its under active development and Taylor spends time in IRC to answer questions as well.

Comment: I just asked there and got no response. I'll try again after some time :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary solution while we wait for better built-in support.

```php
$this->app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->handle(
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput('migrate'),
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput);
```